# I have a page with an absurdly large interline for no reason

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I have a strange problem: one page of my PDF shows really large spaces between lines (between everything except lines of a single paragraph: between itemize items, sections, etc...).

What could be causing that? Screenshot below.

[image]

EDIT: [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/lund-university-economic-history-master-thesis-template/dfbppztvqzdb) is the template (that doesn't seem to have the problem) and [here](https://www.overleaf.com/7812556666pskctszwtzzv) is the template with the minimal modifications to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Without any code that generates this that others can test on their own systems, we cannot help much

Comment: There is no page break points between the section headers. The problem will disappear as soon as you add text after the headers.

Comment: latex never does anything for no reason, you have specified \flushbottom (or used a class that defaults to that)  the sequence of headings can not be broken, ao teh preceding page is short of content so \flushbottom can only be acieved by stretching the content.

Comment: That seems to be the problem (the last page before 4.2 will always have this behavior, no matter how much text I put before), but I could find nowhere `\flushbottom` mentionned... Is there a way to "undo" this behavior with a command?

Comment: I found the template again. [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/lund-university-economic-history-master-thesis-template/dfbppztvqzdb) it is. The problem appears in the 4th chapter, between the first and the second section. [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/7812556666pskctszwtzzv) you can try for yourself (I reproduced the bug with minimal altering of the template).

Comment: Throw in a \vfill where you want a huge gap to appear.